# Azure Diagnostic is not saving logs in azure tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

Just checking the new features introduced in windows azure sdk 2.0 - Enable Diagnostics.

Just created a new azure cloud project with MVC 4 Web Role and enabled diagnostics from the configuration section but the none of the logs are saved on the azure tables - WADLogsTable, WADDiagnosticInfrastructureLogsTable.

diagnostics.wadcfg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration configurationChangePollInterval="PT1M" overallQuotaInMB="4096" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
  <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs />
  <Directories>
    <IISLogs container="wad-iis-logfiles" />
    <CrashDumps container="wad-crash-dumps" />
  </Directories>
  <Logs bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" />
  <WindowsEventLog bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose">
    <DataSource name="Application!*" />
  </WindowsEventLog>
</DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
```

ServiceDefinition.csdef

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="AzureWebApp" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
  <WebRole name="MvcWebApp" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="AzureWebApp" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="3" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
  <Role name="MvcWebApp">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

WebRole.cs -- From MVC Application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;

namespace MvcWebApp
{
    public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        public override void Run()
        {
            // This is a sample webrole implementation. Replace with your logic.

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Trace.WriteLine("Working", "Information");
            }
        }

        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            // For information on handling configuration changes
            // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.

            Trace.WriteLine("Starting Web Role ...", "Information");

            return base.OnStart();
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the Trace.WriteLine error i.e. "Starting Web Role ..." and "Working" to the saved in the azure table - WADLogsTable.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Bhavesh

Comment: Can someone please assistance as to why my simple trace.Writeline is not storing the logs to azure table storage.?

Comment: Diagnostics have a long story known issue of not-working in Compute Emulator. I have almost never succeeded to get logs out of Diagnostics Monitor when running locally! But it works when deployed. For local tracing/diagnostics sessions you can just open the [`Compute Emulator UI`](http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/05/windows-azure-basicscompute-emulator.html), navigate to the `Instance` of the `Role` you want to "monitor" and watch the output.

Comment: Its given here in MSDN check for the Q&A section. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn186185.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add any custom instrumentation code to your OnStart() method if you deploy a `diagnostics.wadcfg` file.

The problem lies in the `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` file that contains `"DevelopmentStorage=true"` -- replace it with your real storage account or make sure that your deployment tool does it.

Comment: I am running the application in local emulator so my local.cscfg and cloud.cscfg are identical. I will update the configuration before publishing my web role to cloud but for now I would like to view the log in the local storage which I am unable view.

I have noticed "WADWindowsEventLogsTable" table in the storage tables, but no WADLogsTable.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write trace lines from `RoleEntryPoint` object.

The `WebRole` instance is running in a different process than the process of your application, and therefor the configurations in your web.config are not affecting it.

See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx) for more information.

Your can either manually set the diagnostics listener:

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        var listener = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener();
        Trace.Listeners.Add(listener);
    }
}
```

Or simply add another config file named `WaIISHost.exe.config` (Remember to set it's Copy to Output Directory property).

In this answer, I assume that trace printing is working fine for you when you use it in other classes.